# What is the inverse of the integrated $\chi^2$ function?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I am implementing some preprocessing of variables in the context of a paper called [A Neural Bayesian Estimator for Conditional Probability Densities](https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0402093).

It states: 1.) Given a non-linear, a monotonous variable transformation $F:t\rightarrow s$ such that $s$ is distributed uniformly is applied. 2.) Afterwards $s$ is scaled to lie between -1 and 1. 3.) Finally, the flat distributions need to be converted into Gaussian distributions, centered at zero with std 1. While the first two steps are clear, I am struggling with the third one.

Regarding 3.), the author further states that the inverse of the integrated $\chi^2$ function may be used.

**Update 1:**

After reading the paper again, it seems that $\chi^2$ doesn't directly relate to chi, but is rather calculated as follows:

$\chi^2$ = P*(1-o)^2+(1-p)*((-1)-o)^2

with `P` as the purity (can be computed easily given some variable) and `o` the variable itself.

For a given $s$ scaled to lie between -1 and 1, I may just calculated the integral with $lower bound=-1$ and $upper bound=s$ and then getting the inverse of it.

Question: How to do this numerically?

Answer (score 1):

Comment: It looks as if you may be using an inverse gamma prior distribution
for Bayesian inference. See Wikipedia on 'inverse gamma distribution'
for details. The inverse chi-squared distribution is a special case
(just as 'regular' chi-squared is a special case of 'regular' gamma).

Inverse gamma distributions are often used in Bayesian inference
as conjugate priors to gamma likelihoods (e.g, arising from normal variance).

Note: If so, this has nothing to do with 'inverting' a CDF (to get a 'quantile' function) for purposes of simulation.

Comment: Does it help to have the inverse of F?

Comment: In simulation one often begins with $U_1, U_2, \dots$ iid $Unif(0,1).$ Then to simulate $X$ with CDF $F$, one uses $X = F^{-1}(U).$ Sorry if I confused the issue by mentioning another kind of 'inverse.:

Comment: I got an update...